# laravel echo with redis and socket io

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, laravel-5

i have an event  SomeEvent.php

like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SomeEvent  implements ShouldBroadcast
{


    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->data = $array;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

i have included the following in my bootstrap.js and compiled it with gulp

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://site.dev:6001'

});

window.Echo.private('channel-name')
    .listen('SomeEvent', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
});
```

then i have installed tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server and here is my laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "appKey": "[generated]",
    "authHost": "http://site.dev",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": "sitei.dev",
    "port": "6001",
    "referrers": [],
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

now when i fire up laravel echo server with laravel-echo-server start it starts up very well however when i fire up the above event like so

```
event(new SomeEvent(json_encode(['name' => 'some-name'])));
```

i can see the event published to redis however nothing is loged to my client console: i am also including socket io in my master.blade.php

the above also happens with notifications

any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks guys

Comment: Are you able to solve this ? I had similar issue still open http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120789/broadcasting-event-with-socket-io-and-redis-in-laravel-5-3?noredirect=1#comment69445395_41120789 any idea?

Comment: There is a typo in your host setting, no? "sitei.dev" vs "site.dev". Could that be it? If not, are you sure a redis worker process is running?

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined an authentication rule for your channel in BroadcastServiceProvider?

Do you see any information about connecting and leaving the channel if you put on devMode in the laravel-echo-server.json?

I had a lot of troubles trying to set up my websocket connection, but a finally figured it out and my code looks pretty much like yours.

Good luck!