# Broadcasting event with Socket.io and Redis in Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, sockets, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a simple event broadcast option with L5.3 using socket.io and Redis.
The things are works fine with server side but not working on the client side.
here is my code.

**Event code**

```
public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    //
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('test-channel');
}
```

**Socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

**View file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('test-channel: App\\Events\\SomeEvent', function(message) {
      alert("not yet reached here")
       jQuery('#dynamic_content').append(message.data.name);
   });
    </script>
```

**event fire code**

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    // Route logic...
    $data = array("id" => "1","name"=>"jobin" , "amount" => "1000");
    Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode($data));
    event(new App\Events\SomeEvent($data));
     return "event fired";
});
```

when I visit **domain.app/test** the node server console already out put the result like below.

```
Message Recieved: {"id":"1","name":"jobin","amount":"1000"}
```

I already tried several thread I' still not able to figure out what I'm missing here.

**My ENV**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

only issue is unable to reflect it on client side ,the console of node server and handle method of EventListener are works fine (I can dump the data there).

Any idea guys last 6 hours working on it.

already tried [these](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/broadcasting-event-works-good-on-server-side-but-not-on-client-side) 
any hint will highly appreciated .
Thank you.

Comment: i think for client side you should use laravel Echo that has direct support or check websocket tab in your network tab of dev tool and verify if event is coming or not.

Comment: but laravel echo required echo server too right ?

Answer (score 2):

Private channels adds  `private_` before the name. In you case the channel name will be `private_test-channel`

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already resolved the issue without using event broadcasting of Laravel.

Comment: @JobinJose Would you mind sharing your code on github or some other place? I'm facing an issue like this and the resources for learning `laravel, socket.io, redis and broadcasting` is scarce